# Check if number is less than another number by a certain percentage

Tags: php

I would like to check if `$Price1` is less than `$Price2` by 40% **or more**.

```
$name = 'bob';
$price1 = '100';
$price2 = '300';

if($price1 < $price2) {
   echo $name;
}
```

The above code doesn't check if `$price1` is less than by a percentage.

Comment: Convert the smaller number to a percentage of the larger. Then do the comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$name = 'bob';
$price1 = '100';
$price2 = '300';

if($price1 < 0.6*$price2) {
   echo $name;
}
```

You would like to echo `'bob'` when `$Price1` is less than `$Price2` by 40% or more. In this case the 'or more' refers to the percentage.

First thing we need to know is what 40% less than `$Price2` is. This is 100% of `$Price2` minus 40% of `$Price2`, in other words 100% minus 40% equals 60% of `$Price2`. That is the same as 0.6 times `$Price2`.

Secondly we try an 'or more' case: Say that we need to know what what 45% less than `$Price2` is. Analogous to the reasoning above this would be 0.55 times `$Price2`. So it is smaller than 0.6, hence the `<` operator between  `$Price1` and `0.6*$Price2`.

Conclusion: We need to test when `$Price1 < 0.6*$Price2` and then echo `'bob'`;

Comment: I know I asked this question a while ago, but would you mind explaining how this answer works?

Comment: It's magic! No, I did add an explanation. I hope it's comprehensible. Sorry, but I find this difficult to explain.